# start script after resume as logged in user (not root)

Tags: bash, scripts, suspend

I'm running owncloud client in Ubuntu and after a suspend/resume there's a bug in owncloud which makes it not be able to connect to the server.

I wrote a little script which should restart owncloud, but it doesn't. 
I've put it in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` and the script runs. 
Contents:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
 case $1 in
     pre)
        echo "$(date) off" >> /var/log/sulog.txt #debugging
    ;;
     post)
         echo "$(date) on" >> /var/log/sulog.txt #debugging
         killall owncloud
         /usr/bin/owncloud
         echo "$(date) started owncloud" >> /var/log/sulog.txt #debugging
    ;;
 esac
```

The script executes as the log file is updated. However it doesn't kill the active owncloud instance and it doesn't start a new one either when I resume after a suspend.

When I run the script in terminal as the current user it works as I want it to.
When I run it in root it kills the owncloud instance, but it then start a new one without the server settings etc. I've worked around that with `sudo -H -u <user> bash <....>` to start it as another user, but then it doesn't work because it doesn't have the keychain unlocked.

*How can I `/usr/bin/owncloud` from within the script (which is run as root) as the current user with the current session so that the icon is also added to the statusbar?*

Answer (score 2):

Your missing the DISPLAY definition. Also, making it depend on Network connection is better. For me on arch linux works:

/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/20-owncloud

```
 #!/bin/sh
 case "$2" in
       up)
               # is called as soon as connection is up
               env DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u yourusername owncloud
       ;;
       down)
               # yes, maybe that is better in system-sleep
               killall owncloud
       ;;
esac
```

The script has to be owned by root:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/20-owncloud
```

Don't forget to make that script executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/20-owncloud
```

and start/enable the NetworkManager dispatcher:

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

At least on arch it works that way, maybe slightly other names in ubuntu.